# How to remove username@hostname from terminal bar?

Tags: terminal, user-account, menu-bar, ios

currently this is how my terminal bar looks like, it's showing my full name and the hostname. I'd like to configure it so that this is removed  and it only shows the directory, but I don't know how.

[image]

Comment: Please enter the following command into your `Terminal`: [return]`echo "${PS1}"` [return] and insert the result within your original question (OQ).

Comment: I inputted ``echo "${PS1}"`` into the terminal and got this output ``${ret_status} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)``. Didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Please enter the following command into your `Terminal`: [return] `echo "$(git_prompt_info)"` [return] and insert the result within your original question (OQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using zsh you can edit your ~/.zshrc file to include this:

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
```

See here for details:
https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/5700#issuecomment-311998546

Comment: Solved my issue.

Comment: Out of many other solutions this one did the job

Comment: Will enabling this setting hide the "users/<username>" in all terminal outputs?

Answer (score 1):

If you go into Terminal and press `Cmd + ,`, it will open up the preferences. Click the Profiles tab on the top.

[image]

Then click the Window tab.

[image]

Then you can set a title and uncheck the "Working directory", "Active Process", and everything else under the Title section.

[image]

This will make it look like this:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. I unchecked everything, but it still shows username@hostname.

Comment: @BP9381, can you edit your post to show a screenshot of the "Window" page?

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps on my MAC

1. nano ~/.zshrc
2. add `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"`
3. go to Preferences of your terminal
4. Under profile > window, change the title to whatever you want
   [image: >]